# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I've got my HTTP interceptor to open loading bar each time HTTP request is made:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const dataStorageService = this.injector.get(DataStorageService);
    dataStorageService.openProgressbar.next(true);
    return next
        .handle(req)
        .do(evt => {
             if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                 dataStorageService.openProgressbar.next(false);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
    }
```

Then in my `data-storage-service` I have a subject:

```
openProgressbar = new Subject<boolean>();
```

And I listen to it in my app component, where I placed my loading bar:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataStorageService.openProgressbar.subscribe(czyOtworzyc => {
        this.alertMessageNavbarStatus = true;
    });
}
```

But the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is showing.
I was looking for solution with using ngAfterContentChecked but it didn't work for me. Could anybody help me?

Comment: use detectchanges manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) into the component

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Run change detection manually

```
ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: i added this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); to end of my ngoninit but still getting the error

Comment: ok I figured it out: ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }